# Why am I unable to see some extensions on Hybris HAC?

Tags: java, content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud

I added the following extensions to localextensions.xml as part of SmartEdit setup.

```
    <!-- Smart Edit -->
<extension name="cmssmartedit"/>
<extension name="cmssmarteditwebservices"/>
<extension name="cmswebservices"/>
<extension name="permissionswebservices"/>
<extension name="previewwebservices"/>
<extension name="smarteditaddon"/>
<extension name="smarteditwebservices" />
```

But I am unable to see cmswebservices , permissionswebservices and previewwebservices on HAC and update the system with these extensions' data.

Comment: have you performed ant clean all and update running system after adding the extensions to  localextensions.xml ?

Comment: Also some extensions need ant addoninstall